# Raster layer changes from transparent to black on certain zoom level

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, mapbox

I upload a geotiff file to mapbox and created a layer with it. It works as expected on zoom level 2 up to 5.4 and then suddenly the background changes from transparent to black. Any ideas why that happens?

You can see the map here:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/felixmichel/cj1550ogw002s2smkgbz60keh.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZmVsaXhtaWNoZWwiLCJhIjoiZWZrazRjOCJ9.62fkOEqGMxFxJZPJuo2iIQ#2.1/-3.499049/50.617268/0

The greyish border next to the coastline is the raster layer.

Comment: Same issue here though at a different zoom.  Ever find an answer @felix?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Answered below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to ensure your transparency is set to 0 instead of NoData.

This article from Mapbox talks about how you can do it with a program called Rasterio:
https://www.mapbox.com/help/troubleshoot-raster-transparency-issues/

It states you need to run this command to set NoData values to zero:

```
rio edit-info --nodata 0 filename255.tif
```

However, I was creating my geoTiff in QGis and there was an option to use 0 for transparency when needed.  So first check whatever software you are using for creating the raster images.